# SQL GROUP BY prioritise value based on other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table something like this:

| value | high_priority | grouping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | one |
| 2 | FALSE | one |
| 3 | FALSE | one |
| 3 | FALSE | two |
| 4 | FALSE | two |

I would like to get the `MAX` value by grouping unless the entry is `high_priority` in which case I should prioritise that over the non `high_priority` entries.

For example, on the above table I want these results:

| value | grouping |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 4 | two |

The simple solution of GROUP BY won't account for the `high_priority` entries:

```sql
SELECT
MAX(value) AS value,
grouping

FROM the_table
GROUP BY grouping
```

How can I extend this to also account for the `high_priority` entries?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you can use aggregation like this:

```
select grouping,
       coalesce(case when max(high_priority) filter (where high_priority) then id end,
                max(id)
               ) as id                
from the_table
group by grouping;
```

However `distinct on` might be a simpler solution:

```
select distinct on (grouping) t.*
from the_table t
order by grouping, high_priority desc;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the group solution seems interesting. Perhaps that could be a better alternative. However, when I had tried the DISTINCT ON based query earlier that also led to some performance issues (I believe due to similar reasons that I gave on Serg's answer). So unfortunately, I couldn't use that option (even though I think it looks the cleanest)

Comment: @KNejad . . . It would be interesting if `group by` were faster than `distinct on`.  Usually, `distinct on` is faster.  You can add an index on `(grouping, high_priority desc)` to speed it up.

Comment: Check `distinct on` version with the  `7 TRUE one` row added.  Is it the  expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively group by grouping, high_priority and row_number the results as needed.

```
SELECT value,  grouping
FROM (
    SELECT
    MAX(value) AS value,
    grouping, high_priority,
    row_number() over(partition by grouping order by high_priority desc) rn
    
    FROM the_table
    GROUP BY grouping,high_priority
)t
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks Serg, I tried something like this as well. Unfortunately, since `high_priority` is a boolean, it doesn't seem to be able to efficiently order by this (since it can't take advantage of indexes). At least that's my best guess as to why a similar solution had performance issues. Do you think this query could lead to performance issues or is it likely something specific to my DB setup that's not shown in the question?

Comment: @KNejad I would expect the query can use index on `grouping, high_priority` when grouping. Hardly any index will help when row_numbering the grouped set.

Answer (score -1):

By joining on the same table and using COALESCE this provides the correct results:

```sql
SELECT
COALESCE(MAX(high_priorities.value), MAX(the_table.value)) AS value,
the_table.grouping

FROM the_table

LEFT JOIN the_table AS high_priorities
ON the_table.grouping = high_priorities.grouping
AND high_priorities.high_priority = TRUE

GROUP BY the_table.grouping
```

This works because in the event that any high priority exists, it will pick that. In the event that none exist the first clause of COALESCE will become NULL and it will fall back to the second option.